# Генерация числа с предварительной "анимацией"

Tags: c#, winforms

мне нужно сделать генерацию числа с анимацией того, как число несколько секунд генерируется, и чтобы это все выводилось на экран.

Пробовал `Thread.Sleep()`, но программа просто зависает (логично); пробовал через асинхронный метод и внутри него `Task.Delay()` - вот такое поведение мне примерно и нужно, все генерируемые числа отображались на экране, но из-за асинхронности я не понимаю как мне контролировать весь последующий код, который не дожидается выполнения предыдущего.
Нужно, чтобы шла генерация и весь следующий код не выполнялся.
Вот как я пробовал:

```
int value1 = 0, value2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   value1 = random.Next(1, 7);
   value2 = random.Next(1, 7);

   startingBucks1.Text = Convert.ToString(value1);
   startingBucks2.Text = Convert.ToString(value2);

   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все просто. Сделал все таки используя асинхронность. Чтобы данный метод можно было использовать внутри другого с припиской `await`, он должен быть не `void`. Сделал возврат `Task`, и внутри метода, где я использую эту генерацию, нужно вызвать метод генерации с припиской `await`.

```
private async void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   infoPanel.Enabled = true;
   buttonPlay.Visible = false;

   await StartingBucksGeneration();
}

private async Task StartingBucksGeneration()
{
   int value1 = 0, value2 = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
      value1 = random.Next(1, 7);
      value2 = random.Next(1, 7);

      startingBucks1.Text = Convert.ToString(value1);
      startingBucks2.Text = Convert.ToString(value2);

      await Task.Delay(100);
   }
            
   currentBucks[0] = value1;
   currentBucks[1] = value2;

   labelBucks1.Text = startingBucks1.Text;
   labelBucks2.Text = startingBucks2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).